# What kind of proxy/store are to be used for user preferences and session variables?

Tags: extjs, session-variables, extjs5

I use the gpl version 5.1.1 of ExtJS, no other library or framework (no ASP...).

---

I use [LocalStorage proxy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage) in a Store to store/save the user preferences. I call "user preferences" the default filter values and other display options. I use LocalStorage because users mostly use the same PC and their preferences can be stored localy.
I don't plan to save these data to the server DB, but I could.

---

I would like to use [Memory proxy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory) for session variables which must be reinitialised every time the user log in.

> This proxy simply uses a local variable for data storage/retrieval, so its contents are lost on every page refresh.

This would work fine for me.

---

I do not use [SessionStorage proxy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorage)... But I could use this proxy for session variables.

> Note that session storage is different to local storage (see Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage) - if a browser session is ended (e.g. by closing the browser) then all data in a SessionStorageProxy are lost.

This would also be a solution. The browser versions are not a problem, they are compatible with SessionStorage.

---

I would like to know if I use the correct principle to store user preferences or if I should use another way.
What is the "best" solution between memory proxy and SessionStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory proxy will only keep the settings for that page load. If you leave the page then everything will be lost. This does not require a specific browser, any browsers will work even IE6. Even is the user is logged into your app, when they leave the page the settings will be lost and will have to be retrieved on next visit.

The session storage proxy (using HTML5's SessionStorage api) will keep the settings in browser memory for the browser's session. You can leave the page and come back to it and the settings will still be there. The settings will be lost when the browser is closed. This requires a HTML5 compliant browser (IE10+). If the user is logged into your app, when they leave the page but come back to it the settings will still be local (unless the browser is closed).

The local storage proxy (using HTML5's LocalStorage api) will keep the settings forever or until cleared programmatically or by the user manually. Leave the page, close the browser and the setting will still be there when the app is visited again (unless otherwise cleared by code or user).

Comment: This is clear for me. My question is: **is it correct** to use LocalStorage proxy for user settings? And **what kind of proxy** should be used for session variables?

Comment: The decision is yours. LocalStorage is fine for long term settings. For user settings, I'd prefer SessionStorage so that the user can come back to the app and have it there still. That depends on your login, does the user have to login on each app visit even without the browser closing? If so then Memory is better as it will be dumped when the page is left.